# Cannot access to Tracking UI for ApplicationMaster, Connection refused

Tags: hadoop

I am updating my cluster from Hadoop 1 to YARN. I know the architecture is more distributed. I have already fixed a 'Connection refused' problem by change all the bind ip to it's real ip. But I don't know how to deal with this issue, I cannot see what's going on when the job is running.

For Example, address like `http://shisoft-hadoopmaster:8088/proxy/application_1405708541410_0001/` give me

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /proxy/application_1405708541410_0001/. Reason:

    Connection refused

Caused by:

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:286)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:80)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:122)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:346)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.WebAppProxyServlet.proxyLink(WebAppProxyServlet.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.WebAppProxyServlet.doGet(WebAppProxyServlet.java:344)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1221)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:66)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:900)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:834)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.webapp.RMWebAppFilter.doFilter(RMWebAppFilter.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:795)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:163)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:118)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:113)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter.doFilter(StaticUserWebFilter.java:109)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2$QuotingInputFilter.doFilter(HttpServer2.java:1192)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:45)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:45)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:399)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:928)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)

Powered by Jetty://
```

My Hadoop version is 2.4.1, and here is my yarn configuration

```
<configuration>
    <!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties -->
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
        <value>shisoft-hadoopmaster:8032</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
        <value>shisoft-hadoopmaster:8030</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
        <value>shisoft-hadoopmaster:8031</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.admin.address</name>
        <value>shisoft-hadoopmaster:8033</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address</name>
        <value>shisoft-hadoopmaster:8088</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.log-aggregation-enable</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

I wonder what is it trying to connect and get refused. And how to fix it.

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

I found this issue was because Application Manager was bind to wrong address `yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address`. But I have already set this in the yarn-core.xml
The way to fix it is to set this value before send this job like

```
final Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://shisoft-hadoopmaster:49000/");
conf.set("mapreduce.framework.name", "yarn");
conf.set("yarn.resourcemanager.address", "shisoft-hadoopmaster:8032");
conf.set("yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address", "shisoft-hadoopmaster:8030");
conf.set("yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address", "shisoft-hadoopmaster:8088");
conf.set("mapreduce.jobhistory.webapp.address", "shisoft-hadoopmaster:19888");
...
 final Job job = new Job(conf, "user news word count");
...
```

I don't know why I have to do this since it have already been set in node configuration files.

Comment: I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 5):

I met this issue when use HA in resourcemanager.

And I solved this by adding `yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address` property in `yarn-site.xml` in both resourcemanager and nodemanager, after restart them I could visit the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
You can start the MR Job History Server with the command
$ mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh start historyserver